# Ruby Global Variables

Tags: ruby, reflection, metaprogramming

In Ruby is there any method that lists all the global variables available at the point of inspection like `$GLOBALS` in php?

Comment: Should this question be tagged `reflection`, or tagged `metaprogramming`?

Comment: Does `$GLOBALS` get included in `$GLOBALS` in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is `Kernel#global_variables`.

> > puts global_variables

Since it's a method from Kernel, you can call it without having to mention the class name.

Comment: @Geo: Thanks for the feedback. Is there any shortcut like $:, $. or something built-into ruby?

Comment: Ruby has some special variables, like in the way Perl does. See http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html , under the section `Predefined variables`.

Comment: I did see the predefined variables in Ruby, but if I am not wrong, there is no predefined variable that acts as a shortcut to the global_variables method.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing in Ruby.

Comment: I cannot find such a thing in the MRI 1.8.7 source